# Another iPhone Memory leak issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, sbjson

I have memory leak on jsonParser.

**Here is my code**

```
- (id) objectWithUrl:(NSURL *)url {
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
NSString *jsonString = [self stringWithUrl:url];

// Parse the JSON into an Object
return [jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil]; }
```

This is the error message I'm getting, **potential leak of an object allocated on line 192 and stored into 'jsonParser'**

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+new is equivalent to the [[SBJsonParser alloc] init] call so you're responsible to release jsonParser object. As you use it in return statement the easiest way to fix leak will be to autorelease it right after creating:

```
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser new] autorelease];
```

Comment: In addition, you should consider sending `alloc` and `init` messages to classes instead of `new`, while these are functionally equivalent, technically `new` is not part of Objective-C and is not what is widely used by the community.

[Here are a few more reasons to use `alloc` and `init` instead of `new`.](http://macresearch.org/difference-between-alloc-init-and-new)

Comment: @Thuggish: Technically, `alloc` and `init` are not part of Objective-C.  They are part of the Foundation framework.   In fact `new` predates them and actually derives from Smalltalk. Anyway, your point stands.  Everybody uses `alloc` `init`.  `new` looks a bit odd in the context of Objective-C.

Comment: You'll likely see `new` used more and more often in the context of ARC, it seems.